How to make btrfs compression level setting propagate to files and folders
I have a btrfs filesystem I am using compression on.  I want set the compression level on a folder:
btrfs property set -t <folder> compression zstd:8

Which correctly sets the type and level of compression for the folder.  The type of compression is subsequently inherited by objects in the folder, but not the compression level.  All new objects in the folder appear with compression "zstd" with no compression level.
How do you make compression level propagate?
